# Making cookies with php and perl

Tags: php, perl, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie using PHP, so it's the same as the one output by the Perl code below:

```
my %auth;
$auth{'username'} = $username;
$auth{'password'} = $password;
my $wholesaleauth = $co->cookie
(
 -name=>'wholesaleauth',
 -value=>\%auth,
 -expires=>'+1h',
 -path=>'/'
);
```

Now I do not know perl and all and do not want to change the perl code. I need to basically mimic the cookie. When I look at the cookie in my chrome cookie management it says the value is:

```
password&PASSWORD&username&USERNAME
```

I am trying to basically mimic that but in PHP.

Comment: I am basically wanted to create a cookie in php and then the already built perl script will read the cookie and login (will be redirected to the perl script). The perl already has a login interface but I am wanting to redo it in php to add more functionality to the login. The perl sets a cookie with the following content: password&PASS&username&USER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work properly but using setrawcookie instead. That would not use percent coding and was able to be identical to the perl set cookie.

Answer (score 3):

I understand you are only trying to port the existing script. However, assuming those are really the user name and password people used to log in to the site, I would say you have a [major security hole](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=29928).

Other than that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use CGI::Cookie;

my %auth;
$auth{'username'} = 'not safe';
$auth{'password'} = 'get me outta here';

my $wholesaleauth = CGI::Cookie->new(
    -name=>'wholesaleauth',
    -value=>\%auth,
    -expires=>'+1h',
    -path=>'/'
);

print "Set-Cookie: $wholesaleauth\n";
```

Outputs:

`Set-Cookie: wholesaleauth=password&get%20me%20outta%20here&username&not%20safe;
path=/; expires=Thu, 14-Jan-2010 08:05:12 GMT`

[Cookies work in a common way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation) regardless of the language or library used to construct or output them.

See also the section titled [drawbacks of cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Drawbacks_of_cookies).

Comment: +1 Always important to understand the underlying protocol itself when trying to make something work in code.  Glad you posted the link to Wikipedia...and I'm sure it references the original RFC.

Comment: I already informed the client that the perl code wasn't very well secure when I noticed it stores the password and username in the cookie, but they don't have the budget for a full rewrite so this is what I have to work with. Plus I do not know perl, just making a user interface in php.

Comment: @AJ: For reference, I think cookies are described in http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html

Answer (score 2):

not tested and $value is made up. Put in your own $value

```
$username="username";
$password="password";
$auth['password']=$password;
$auth['username']=$username;
$value = "password\&".$auth['password']."\&username\&".$auth['username'];
echo $value;
setcookie("wholesaleauth", $value, time()+3600,"/");
```

see the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for more info

Comment: Didn't seem to work, adds %'s into the content for the cookie.

Comment: @mikelbring: Those `%`s are part of the standard way to encode strings (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). I am left to wonder why you are in charge of coding anything related to web site security as you seem not to know enough to know what you don't know.

Comment: I was wondering my self why the perl script puts the username and password into the cookies, but that is something I cannot change. I am simply making a php front door to the perl script, where the user logins into the site using php and is able to do varies user related functions (change password), I needed to be able to replicate the cookies the perl uses for user auth so the user can go to that part of the site with out re-logging in.

Comment: @ghostdog74 When I use your method, it puts password%26PASSWD%26username%26USERN into the cookie content, but when  you login with the perl code it puts password&PASSWD&username&USERN ,  now I understand its the same thing but the perl script still thinks I'm logged out.

Answer (score 1):

That cookie doesn't look quite right, what library are you using in perl (the $co->cookie parts)? I'd suggest CGI::Cookie in perl:

http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Cookie.html

Then you can get cookies in PHP via the $_COOKIE['cookiename'] variable, and set them via setcookie:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: I am just looking at the script I am working with. I did not write it, I do not know any perl at all. Basically I am rewriting the login using php but then it will redirect to the perl code with a set cookie.